# Fubini's theorem in higher dimensions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is Fubini's theorem applicable in higher dimensions? For instance, I have the following product of integrals
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t'} f(t',t'') dt'' dt' \int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t'} g(t',t'') dt'' dt'
\end{equation}
is this the same as
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{t} \int_{0}^{t'} \int_{0}^{\tau} \int_{0}^{\tau'} f(\tau',\tau'') g(\tau',\tau'') d\tau'' d\tau' dt'' dt'
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes. But as always: Fubini may fail in pathological cases, so make sure your functions are not too ugly

Comment: @b00nheT What's the formal proof?

Comment: If you go to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem#Proofs you can find the idea of all such proofs, which is the classic measure-theoretic approach. I've seen a couple during my studies which you can conveniently find in https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf